# Why does the µ-H curve of look like this?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If we consider a solenoid consisting of a wire coiled around a ferromagnetic core and observe the relationship between $B$ and $H$, we see that as the current through the coil increases, the material enters the saturation at a point where $B$ can't increase anymore.

What I don't understand is what happens to the $µ_rH$ curve on a physical level? Why does it suddenly fall when material enters saturation?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is what saturation is: a further increase in $H$ does not change the magnetization anymore. The magnetic domains are already aligned with the magnetizing field.

In this figure, the permeability curve is basically the derivative of the magnetization. Around the $H$-value of $1000$ ampere-turns per meter, the value of $B = \mu_r \mu_0 H \approx 10^3 \times 4\pi \cdot10^{-7} \times 10^3 \approx 1$ T, which approaches the saturation magnetization of iron.